# How to Start Server for ReactJS using yarn as a beginner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learning ReactJS today since I know some JavaScript.

Now, I want to know how I start something like this:

I have installed Node.js on Windows, and after that, I was able to do this:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Which gave a reply of this sort:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarnpkg -> C:\Users\EMI\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn -> C:\Users\EMI\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
+ yarn@1.7.0
updated 1 package in 16.303s
```

From my understanding, it means that the application was installed correctly.

**How do I start the server to show a simple "Hello World" program in ReactJS using Yarn?**

Answer (score 1):

Yarn is only a package manager. If you want to start a server to show a simple Hello World program, I'd suggest using something like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) or write your own express server

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting to learn react, knowing about [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) is highly useful. YOu can visit the page for more information which has good description on how to start your hello world and much more.

create-react-app creates a basic template for you to start learning react right away. You just need to commands,

1) npm install and,
2) npm start(which starts the server)